# Flutter: Send data to parent page & Reload

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter but I'm in love with it! :D

I'm doing a small application. It requires reloading the parent page when coming back from the child page.

I'm using Navigator.push() method to move between pages. I want to reload the parent page after calling Navigator.pop() method.

How can I do that?

Thanks,

-Naveed

Answer (score 1):

On first widget

```
onPressed:() async {
    var value = await Navigator.pushNamed(context,"/second");
    setState(){
        print(value);
    }
}
```

on second widget

```
Navigator.pop(context, param);  //pass parameter here
```